# Pycharm: Is there key shortcut for moving between instances of variable/function?

Tags: pycharm

I've looked in Pycharm documentation for available shortcuts, and could not find the one that i use(d) the most in Visual Studio : Ctrl+Shift + up/down arrows - which moves between instances of variable/function.
Am I missing something? 
Is there any other way to do this?
(I'm using Pycharm 4.0.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Ctrl-Shift-F7 to highlight the usages of the variable under caret and then use F3/Shift-F3 to navigate between the usages.

Comment: Ok, somewhat less intuitive than in VS, but still does the job.

Comment: I also like Ctrl+Shift+I to show definition, followed by move to definition as needed